# docker: not found' Error when building a docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

I am trying to build a docker image inside a Jenkins pod.  However, I got the below errors.  When I login to the Jenkins pod, I cannot find the docker command.  I have installed all plugins related to Jenkins and am using 'jenkins/jenkins:lts' image from docker hub.

/tmp/jenkins2842149568243187838.sh
docker: not found build step 'execute shell' marked build as failure

I am not sure about this issue